# Count the occurrence of each character in a string and put it in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I'm counting the occurrences of each letter in a string from a Java file I scanned earlier on. I've removed all unnecessary characters from the string and the string now contains only unicode letters.
An example:

```
String letters = "wecanendupclimbingthewrongladderandpursuesomeoneelsesversionofsuccess";
```

So let's say I create an array to contain the frequency of each letter.

```
int[] frequency = new int[26];
```

And I'm putting the occurrences in order according to the letters in the alphabet.
So let's say a is 5, and b is 3 and c is 10. It should be something like this:

```
frequency = {5, 3, 10};
```

How best do you think I can do this?

Comment: You have the right idea

Comment: Sorry I don't get you.

Comment: Typically character counts would be modeled with a `Map<Character, Integer>` (or even better, a `Multiset<Character>`). But an array will work too, it's just less type-safe and clear. What are you struggling with?

Comment: @Lio - You are on right track. Check the [answer by sc0der](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879954/10819573).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the index of character related to the `frequency` array by `(ch - 'a')`

Subtract character 'a' from the character

```
        String letters = "aaaabbabbz";
        letters = letters.toLowerCase();
        int[] frequency = new int[26];
        for (char ch : letters.toCharArray()) {
            int index = ch - 'a';
            frequency[index]++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(frequency));

        // in case you want only the characters that appear you can use IntStream and filter
        int[] result = IntStream.of(frequency).filter(i -> i > 0).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

, output

```
[5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[5, 4, 1]
```

Comment: shouldn't the last count of the first line of output be `1`?

Comment: I have edited the post and forget to update the output :)

Answer (score 1):

The good solution would be using a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) in order to keep the characters sorted alphabetically and then get the corresponding list of values (number of occurrences) after looping over the characters.

Here is an example:

```
String str = "wecanendupclimbingthewrongladderandpursuesomeoneelsesversionofsuccess";
Map<Character,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for(char c : str.toCharArray())
    map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0)+1);
System.out.println(map.values());
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 4, 4, 11, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 7, 5, 2, 4, 8, 1, 4, 1, 2]
```

If you want to include absent characters (those with zero occurrences in the string), you can initialize the map with all the alphabets at first as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    map.put((char)(97 + i), 0);
```

Then, the output would be:

```
[3, 1, 4, 4, 11, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 7, 5, 2, 0, 4, 8, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: There are some problems here: too much code, too complicated, and describing it as "best"

Comment: @Bohemian where is the complicated part? Can it be simplified? Isn't using a ``Map`` the best solution for such a case? Feel free to edit the answer if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Using a TreeSet is more complicated than needed because it doesn't automatically cater for missing letters, so you have to prime the structure before use. A simple `int[]` is the best IMHO - hardly any code needed and it's so clear. Yes, you can simplify the loop body to just one line (see if you can figure it out - look at the methods of Map!).

Comment: Guess my next Java lesson is in Maps and TreeMap?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways to skin this cat, I think the easiest thing might be sort based off of the character ASCII value.  So for example 'a' is valued at 97, so whatever letter you encounter just cast it and subtract 97 to fit it into the proper place in the array (assuming you want arr[0] = frequency of 'a', arr[1] = frequency of 'b', etc).  So if you occurred letter 'letter', just increment the array value at index int(letter) - 97, if that makes sense.  Again, plenty of ways to solve this problem and your thought process is good.

Or as mentioned in the comments you could just use a key/value map lol